# MVC Architecture : Link between JSP and Servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

Which function can be used to check which JSP has invoked a controller Servlet? I mean I have a common controller for many JSP pages ,then how to know which has invoked the servlet? I am using MVC Architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a controller(servlet) across many jsp pages is not exactly a good idea.
However, if you insist to share the controller.

```
<!--some random jsp page-->
<form action="your_controller" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="from" value="from.jsp"/>
</form>
```

And in the controller

```
//omit servlet boilerplate
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception{
    String from = req.getParameter("from");
    //do something base on your "from"
}
```